# jquery: how to pickup variable after leaving text-input

Tags: jquery, focusout

I am trying to change the value of the form's `action` attribute based on the value a user enters into the `wetterInput` field in the code below.

```
<form method="POST" class="formSearch" id="formSearch" action="">
    <input type="text" name="wetterInput" id="wetterInput" class="wetterInput" />
    <input type="submit" class="weatherButton" value="Suchen" />
</form>
```

For example, if the user inputs the text "town", the form's action should be updated to `action="/folder/town/"`.

I've tried the following, but have been unable to get it to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wetterInput').on('focusout', function() {    
        var action = document.getElementById("wetterInput").value;    
        $("#formSearch").attr("action", "/folder/" + action + "/");
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you mean `document`? You have `documetn`

Answer (score 2):

- You've mistyped `document` as `documetn`.
- Be aware that `focusout` doesn't work in Firefox – you should probably be using `blur` instead.
- `var action = this.value;` would probably be cleaner than `var action = documetn.getElementById("wetterInput").value;`

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e789ueb3/1/